# Equivalent of Underscore.js _.pluck in jQuery

Tags: jquery, underscore.js

Does anyone know of a 'pluck' plugin that matches the underscore array method?

```
pluck_.pluck(list, propertyName)
```

A convenient version of what is perhaps the most common use-case for map: extracting a list of property values.

```
var stooges = [{name : 'moe', age : 40}, {name : 'larry', age : 50}, {name : 'curly', age : 60}];
_.pluck(stooges, 'name');
=> ["moe", "larry", "curly"]
```

Google is not helping me much today.
Any pointers much appreciated

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can do it with an expression;

```
var arr = $.map(stooges, function(o) { return o["name"]; })
```

Comment: I was about to use the above solution, but then realized in testing that it is different from _.pluck in some edge cases.  If the 'name' property as used above is null or undefined in any object in the array, this function will just omit that element from the arr output entirely, leaving a smaller array than one began with.  The following covers this: var arr = []; $.each(stooges, function(i,o) { return arr.push(o["name"]); });

Answer (score 22):

just write your own

```
$.pluck = function(arr, key) { 
    return $.map(arr, function(e) { return e[key]; }) 
}
```

Answer (score 9):

It's quite simple to implement this functionality yourself:

```
function pluck(originalArr, prop) {
    var newArr = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < originalArr.length; i++) {
        newArr[i] = originalArr[i][prop];
    }
    return newArr;
}
```

All it does is iterate over the elements of the original array (each of which is an object), get the property you specify from that object, and place it in a new array.

Answer (score 1):

In simple case:

```
var arr = stooges.map(function(v) { return v.name; });
```

More generalized:

```
function pluck(list, propertyName) {
    return list.map(function (v) { return v[propertyName]; })
}
```

But, IMHO, you should not implement it as tool function, but use the simple case *always*.

2018 update:

```
var arr = stooges.map(({ name }) => name);
```