# Find and remove first matching element in an array of Javascript objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

Suppose I have an array:

```
    members = [
        {name: 'Anna', class: 'one'}, 
        {name: 'Bob', class: 'two'},  
        {name: 'Chuck', class: 'two'}];

    removed = members.myRemoveByClass('two');     //something like

    // removed is {name: 'Bob', class: 'two'} 
    // members is [{name: 'Anna', class: 'one'}, {name: 'Chuck', class: 'two'}]
```

I'm looking for something for `myRemoveByClass`. ES2015 is fine or using Lodash. The array will have been ordered already. [None](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25726066/equivalent-of-underscore-pluck-in-pure-javascript) of the [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10457264/how-to-find-first-element-of-array-matching-a-boolean-condition-in-javascript) I've [seen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590865/from-an-array-of-objects-extract-value-of-a-property-as-array) quite [match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10457264/how-to-find-first-element-of-array-matching-a-boolean-condition-in-javascript) what I'm [looking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21659888/javascript-find-and-remove-object-in-array-based-on-key-value) for.

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: Could you point to where it says we need to show what kind of attempt was made. Should I put the number of hours I spend on the problem or link to all the SO solutions that didn't address the question I asked. Such as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25726066/equivalent-of-underscore-pluck-in-pure-javascript https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10457264/how-to-find-first-element-of-array-matching-a-boolean-condition-in-javascript https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35136306/what-happened-to-lodash-pluck etc. Putting my efforts here would not clarify the question.

Comment: `Putting my efforts here would not clarify the question.` It would help illustrate that this isn't a no-effort homework dump or write-my-code-for-me-from-scratch question, which are frowned on - see the first two links in my comment above. Searching existing questions for code that does what you want isn't the same thing as trying to write code yourself

Comment: @CertainPerformance `It would help illustrate that this isn't a no-effort homework dump or write-my-code-for-me-from-scratch question` Isn't that the whole point of reputation? `isn't the same thing as trying to write code yourself` Why do you assume that I didn't spend a couple of hours  trying to code it myself which I did, and finding my code was not helpful in framing the question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could create your own Array class:

```
 class Members extends Array {
   removeByClass(className) {
     for(const [index, member] of this.entries())
        if(member.class === className) 
           return this.splice(index, 1)[0];
   }
}
```

Use it as

```
 const members = new Members([ {/*...*/}, {/*...*/} ]);
 members.removeByClass("...");
```

*PS: "class" is a very bad name as it is a reserved keyword*

Comment: I was going to change it, but ESLint didn't seemed to mind `class` there so I left it in! I don't want to edit it now so that the solutions match the question!

Answer (score 19):

You can use [Array.prototype.findIndex()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex):

> The `findIndex()` method returns the *index* of the first element in the array **that satisfies the provided testing function**. Otherwise, it returns -1, indicating no element passed the test.

Then [`splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) the object by that *index*.

```js
let members = [
        {name: 'Anna', class: 'one'}, 
        {name: 'Bob', class: 'two'},  
        {name: 'Chuck', class: 'two'}];
let idx = members.findIndex(p => p.class=="two");
if(idx >= 0){ //check if item found
  var removed = members.splice(idx, 1);     
  console.log(removed);
  console.log(members);
}
else{ //or not
  console.log('Not found!');
}
```

Comment: This is **dangerously wrong** - if no element is found, `idx` will be -1, and then `members.splice(idx, 1)` will remove the last element of `members`, which is *not* what you want in that case...

Answer (score 3):

You could find the index of the first occurence and check this index and splice the object from the array.

```js
var members = [{ name: 'Anna', class: 'one' }, { name: 'Bob', class: 'two' }, { name: 'Chuck', class: 'two' }],
    index = members.findIndex(o => o.class === 'two'),
    removed = index !== -1 && members.splice(index, 1);

console.log(removed);
console.log(members);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

This would also work

```
removeByClass(array, filterString) {
   const memberToRemove = array.find(element => {
     return element.class === filterString;
   });
   array.splice(array.indexOf(memberToRemove), 1);
 }

 let members = [
  { name: 'Anna', class: 'one' },
  { name: 'Bob', class: 'two' },
  { name: 'Chuck', class: 'two' }];

this.removeByClass(members, 'two');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use create an `Array.prototype.removeByProp` to remove first element found by `prop` equal to `value` using [Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) and [Array.prototype.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Code example:

```js
const members = [{ name: 'Anna', class: 'one' }, { name: 'Bob', class: 'two' }, { name: 'Chuck', class: 'two' }]

Array.prototype.removeByProp = function (prop, value) {
  this.find((o, i) => {
    if (o?.[prop] === value) {
      this.splice(i, 1)
      return true
    }
    return false
  })
  return this
}

console.log(members.removeByProp('class', 'two'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply:

```
function removeByClass(obj, prop) {
    for (let i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
        if (obj[i].class == prop) obj.splice(i, 1);
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `some` method to find the `member` which needs to be removed and return `true` to stop the loop.

```js
let members = [
  {name: 'Anna', class: 'one'}, 
  {name: 'Bob', class: 'two'},  
  {name: 'Chuck', class: 'two'}
];

function myRemoveByClass(members, className) {
  let foundMember = null;
  members.some((member, index) => {
    if (member.class == className) {
      members.splice(index, 1);
      foundMember = member;
      return true;
    }
  });
  
  return foundMember;
}

let removed = myRemoveByClass(members, 'two');
console.log(removed);
console.log(members);
```

As Jonas pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53534773/5640621), you should avoid using `class` as it is a reserved word.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `without` and `findWhere`

```
var arr = _.without(members , _.findWhere(members , {
 class: "two"
}));
```

Comment: does this require lodash? seems like it's lodash syntax